# Null check in where?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have the following:

```
var tagId = "5288";
source.Where(p => p.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("picker").Contains(tagId));
```

This returns the error  `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`

So some of the returned results, does not contain a picker value. How would I check for this, in the above statement?

It is a Umbraco Multinode treepicker that is the "picker" value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the result of `GetPropertyValue` can be `null` if the `picker` value is not found. In that case, you can use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```c#
source.Where(p => p.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("picker")?.Contains(tagId) == true);
```

Note the `?.` after `GetPropertyValue`. If that method returns `null` then it's not `true`, so those will not be included in the filtered objects.

Comment: That == true statement is not necessary. :P

Comment: @OlegMusijenko It is necessary. Using the null conditional operator changes the type to `bool?` which isn't implicitly convertible to `bool` which is the required result of the predicate in a `Where`. Alternatively, you could coalesce to false with `?? false`, but directly comparing to true is likely more clear for your future maintainers.

Comment: It is indeed necessary @OlegMusijenko. Without it, `p.GetPropertyValue<...>("picker")?.Contains` evaluates to `null`. The explicit `== true` makes it a boolean condition.

Comment: @brother Please mark this as the correct answer if it's what you needed... :)

Comment: @MattU jep, still 1 minute to go, before i can ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
source.Where(p => 
{
    var pickerVal = p.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("picker");
    if (pickerVal == null)
        return false;
    return pickerVal.Contains(tagId);
});
```

or more condensed:

```
source.Where(p => 
{
    var pickerVal = p.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("picker");
    return (pickerVal != null) && pickerVal.Contains(tagId);
});
```

Comment: These solutions work, but using a null conditional operator is even more condensed. Null conditionals save a lot of explicit null checking (`something == null`).